# xcode 6 unable to process application. The bundle '*' is not signed using an apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, codesign

I'm running into the following error when using XCode 6 to validate or submit an ios app to the app store.

I know there are posts out there with this same error, but I've followed all the steps and still can't figure this out.

What I've tried.

1. Change "Valid Architectures" in Build Settings to
   "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)".
2. Re-creating all certificates and
   provisioning profiles.  Deleting and re-downloading to local
   computer.  Syncing these via xcode account preferences page.
3. Installed the apple root certificates

Note. this builds and runs fine in debug mode, I can even export the archived app.  It's only when validating.

Comment: btw in your 2nd graphic you forgot to black out the provisioning profile name ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up...

- Creating a new user on my mac.
- Copied the project over the one of the new users directory.
- Deleted the ios distribution cert and re-created it along with new provisioning profiles.
- Synced the new certs and profiles to my new user's directory and this fixed it.

So there had to be some mis-configuration with my existing user.  When in doubt, start fresh and it may "just work"

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Project's Target > Build Settings > Code Signing and check that your build schemas have the correct Provisioning Profile(s) selected.

Do this **after you're sure that**:

1. Your certificates are valid.
2. Your provisioning profile(s) are valid and that are using the correct App ID which should also exactly match the one in iTunes Connect. Also be sure the Provisioning Profile is an App Store Distribution one (be sure to name it accordingly so you can find it easily).
3. You've refreshed your account in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Your Account > View Details > Refresh.

After you've done all this steps and you're positive regarding your code signing selections, clean your project, select your device as the build device (even if it's not connected), Archive > Validate > Submit.

Comment: I've been through those steps at least 5 times now.  Verified the certificates are valid, created new ones since my old ones are about to expire.  Generated new provisioning profiles off the new certificates.  Deleted old ones from my computer.  Refreshed my account in xcode preferences to sync new certs and provisioning profiles and still the same error.

Comment: And in Code Signing everything is as it should be?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded a shot of my code signing settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

On XCODE 6.0.1 the issue was for me (OS X 10.10) to recreate new apple ID (although my apple ID was already there) so go to Preferences - Delete your current Apple ID account and + add again your apple ID. That did the trick.